# Refresh browser from system call

Tags: c, browser, system-calls

I have the  Javascript:window.location.reload() function which makes my browser to be refreshed by doing it from the .htm page, but I want to make the same from a system call in C, basically, I need to refresh the browser page from a system call in C. is it possible?

Comment: First of all why? Second of all it's possible but would require a lot of work and not get you much.

Comment: You will certainly not be able to find a common programatic access to all browsers, but you might get it kind of working by simulating an F5 key press on the browser window. A macro recorder would be best suited for that kind of job, but you can do it in C too.

Comment: i'm working with BOA server and i just added a new functionality, which executes a bash script from a system call in C  and i can see it in my web page, the first process can be seen, but the second process, just when the first one is done, it can be seen only if i update the browser from javascript or the refresh button, but it is actually from the .htm page, and i need to control it from C, so it would be useful to execute something that refreshes the browser from a system call in my C code at the end of the process, it could also be a bash command.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the browser. Basically, you need to use some form of IPC (Inter-Process Communication) for your program to talk to the web browser, *and* the web browser has to support this in giving you a way to control it.

[Internet Explorer does this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh995096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by exposing a COM interface. Your C program can get a handle to an IE window as an [IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface object, and then call the `Refresh()` method.

I believe [Chrome supports this as well](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication) (via a different mechanism, not COM; see page for details) but honestly I know almost nothing about it and just found that page via a quick Google search (for "Chrome IPC").